# Typescript MarkNullable helper

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to create `MarkNullable` helper to mark some object properties as nullable?

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgJwNYDkCuAbDcBGGIA8AKgDRQDSUEAHsBAHYAmAzlEhCAPYBmURAfFAC8UAPIBbAJbBiZcoIBkUAAqSAxklkVBAegBUUABacA7lGCco4xEihxW9TBgD8UPToDcAWABQv0JBQABrCUADevlBRdgBcUI7iOBAIJJHROHEJSQi%20AL6%20-uDQAJqh8MjoWLj4BEFkAORw9fwFPmqc9MzAUCBxpSJhuXascPQgrSAAdHChjlhQOjp2UMzGmIxQSfFoiclQAD7bWL5TMyIAjCeTOKHnQA)

```
type MarkNullable<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Pick<T, K> /* how to mark as null? */;

type X = {
    a: number,
    b: number
}

type Y = MarkNullable<X, 'a'>

const y: Y = {} as any

y.a = null // a should be number | null
y.a = 1
y.b = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```js
type X = {
    a: number,
    b: number
}
type MarkNullable<Obj, NullableKey> = {
    [Prop in keyof Obj]: Prop extends NullableKey ? Obj[Prop] | null : Obj[Prop]
}

type Y = MarkNullable<X, 'a'>

declare let y: Y

y.a // number | null
y.b // number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBADTgXjgb1HLcCGAuOAOwFcBbAIxgCcAaTbcgki60AX1EljgFkcqA1gDliAG1E5yomAB4A8uQBWNOCPGTpAaRgQAfCnT0sAbQAKVAPZQ4AS0JwBOiwDM4CxQF0C5q3BgAPMBhCABMAZ1UxCSkYbQg4AH43JTNLKA84AB8iKLgCd1SrD3ZQTmh4AE0DPkE1aOkZBBUAchxm3VKQEJgAYwkqeGkwOAgCCs6IADocOAB6WZyWKiyc8VAp8jmF5koqIA)

Please keep in mind, TS does not track mutations, hence in order to narrow `y.a` to `number` you should use `if condition`:

```js
if(y.a){
 y.a // number
}
```